# Detection of Loopable Audio sample

Tags: audio, frequency-spectrum, python, audio-processing

I have a bunch of samples some of which are loopable [1]. I'm searching for a methodology to programmatically detect them.

Any paper or approach is welcomed. Thanks.

[1] https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Loop_(music)

Comment: What approaches did you try? Time domain auto correlation?

Comment: I tried this (https://github.com/AudioCommons/ac-audio-extractor) ready-to-use module. However, it has very poor performance in terms of accuracy. 

What is usage of autocorrelation for this problem? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: How do you define the difference between a loopable and a "not loopable" sample? Everything can be looped by simply repeating it.

Comment: The definition of the loopable audio sample can be found in the Wikipedia link given in the post. The opposite of a loopable audio sample is a one-shot audio sample.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to provide much help withouth knowing the nature of the samples (sounds) and exactly how you define a file to be "loopable". So, I will try to provide an approach making as less assumptions as possible.

First prerequisite for a sound file to be loopable is to match your project's time signature and tempo. Thus, with knowing those two you can calculate how long a bar lasts like

$$ t = signature \cdot 4 \cdot \frac{60}{ tempo} $$

where $t$ is the duration of one bar, $signature$ the time signature of the project and $tempo$ is the tempo in bpm of your project. Additionally, I have assumed that the bpm value always corresponds to the duration of one fourth. The fraction above calculates the duration of one fourth while the multiplying it with $4$ calculates the duration of a whole bar in $\frac{4}{4}$ time signature. Multiplying that with your time signature gives you the result in your time signature (as it is always referenced against $\frac{4}{4}$). For example, for time signature of $\frac{4}{4}$ you get $4$, which when multiplied with the fraction gives the duration of one bar for the given tempo. Similarly, for time signature $\frac{3}{8}$ you get that the bar's duration is

$$ t = \frac{3}{8} \cdot 4 \cdot \frac{60}{tempo} = \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{60}{tempo} = \frac{90}{tempo} $$

As you can see, the first multiplication always results in how many fourths fit into your bar. Then multiplying with the duration of a fourth for the given tempo you get the duration of the bar.

Now, if you get this duration you can check the sound file you have to see which fit the criterion

$$ dur = n \cdot t $$

where $dur$ is the duratio of the sound file, $n$ is an positive integer number and $t$ is the bar duration given above.

Next, you would like to make sure that they end and start at the same value so as to not introduce discontinuities. This is the tricky part due to some factors

- There will always be noise in the recording so there's not an easy chance to start and end in the same value.
- There are tolerances in the human sound perception mechanisms as to how sensitive it is to hearing discontinuities and this is bandwidth, duration and "auditory masking" dependent.

A possible approach would be to calculate a running/moving RMS with small window calculation on the wrapped around version of a file and when you don't get abrupt changes consider this to be a file that starts and ends in approximately the same amplitude.

A possible implementable formula for the running/moving RMS calculation is

$$ RMS \left[ k + 1 \right] = \sqrt{ RMS^{2} \left[k \right] - \frac{1}{N} x^{2} \left[k - N \right] + \frac{1}{N} x^{2} \left[ k + 1 \right]}$$

where $k$ represents the current value and $N$ the total window length. Please note two things about this formula. First, it's response speed depends on the value of $N$ with higher values corresponding to slower response (but in a statistical manner better results). Second, this is a "forward running" formula (this is not a standard term and I use it here abusively). This means that what you see as a result is the RMS value of the current and past $N - 1$ values of the signal. There are other implementations that resemble a "middle running" algorithm (again the term is used abusively here) where you calculate an RMS value for each sample based on $\frac{N - 1}{2}$ samples before and $\frac{N - 1}{2}$ samples after the current value. This may prove to be a better solution for your case but I haven't tested so I can't say for sure.

There might be other approaches to solve your problem too, but I believe that the two conditions set here should pretty much always be satisfied.